# Delete a second row if it's found in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Im trying to delete a row in MySql if there are 2 rows for a merchant. It doesn't matter which row is deleted.

When I run:

```
SELECT * FROM products.merchant_configs WHERE `configKey` = 'CHECK_BALANCE_SUBJECT'
AND merchantId = 6;
```

I see:

[image]

Now I try to delete one of the rows:

```
DELETE FROM products.merchant_configs
WHERE id = (
    SELECT id FROM products.merchant_configs WHERE `configKey` = 'CHECK_BALANCE_SUBJECT'
    AND merchantId = 6
    LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1
);
```

I receive the error:

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'merchant_configs' for update in FROM clause
```

What's going on?

Comment: First of all, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless - which renders the logic of your query unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Nest the query inside another select statement:

```
DELETE FROM products.merchant_configs
WHERE id = (SELECT t.id FROM (
    SELECT id FROM products.merchant_configs WHERE `configKey` = 'CHECK_BALANCE_SUBJECT'
    AND merchantId = 6
    LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1
) t);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gRQPpjtcFUKRYw4WrnaKjK/0).